# Sequelize: add default scope with a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I was working on adding default scopes with function under the Sequelize ORM. I followed the tutorials here http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/scopes.html while for Scope takes arguments, we need to pass on object like this

```
Project.scope('random', { method: ['accessLevel', 19]}).findAll();
```

So inside my video model code, I add a scope called 'defaultScope'

```
Video.addScope(
  'defaultScope',
  (userId) => { 
  *********** scope description here*********
})
```

And this is how I use my model:

```
const videos = await models.video.scope({
    method: ['defaultScope', 'I hardcode userId here']
}).findAll();
console.log(videos);`
```

But I always got an error `(node:43214) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeScopeError: Invalid scope null called.`
If I use another scope name instead of 'defaultScope', my code works and I successfully got the objects back. However since it's a broad level scope I want to make it default. I just feel so confused why the normal scope works but default one not. Can somebody with relevant experience help me figure this out? Thanks!

Comment: I suspect defaultScope cannot have an argument.  The doc says "The default scope is always applied" to  a plain `model.findAll()`.  Thus, I'd say your usage is actually applying defaultScope twice: once implicitly, WITHOUT an argument and again explicitly WITH an argument.

Comment: Yes I took a look at the Sequelize source code. The defaultScope can only be applied to _.isPlainObject for scope options within `model.findAll()`. While for function scope, a normal named one will work. Thanks!